# Use software installed from a re-useable workflow

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to use GitHub actions re-useable workflows. The basic idea is:

- abstract out common tasks (here install `quarto`)
- call the action that installs `quarto` from another action
- use quarto to perform a task

So if I have the common task and it looks like this:

### cm-job.yml

```yaml
name: cm-job

on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    
    steps:
      - name: Setup Quarto
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/setup@v2
        with:
          version: '1.3.450'
```

Then that workflow is called from **reuse.yml**:

```yaml
name: test reuse

on:
  push:

jobs:
  cm-job: 
    uses: ./.github/workflows/cm-job.yml
  setup-quarto:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: [cm-job] 

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Render Quarto Project
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/render@v2
        with:
          to: html # If set, it will be equivalent to `quarto render --to html`
          path: test.qmd
```

So that work as far as creating the dependency on `cm-job` and waiting for it to finish (via `needs: [cm-job]`) but then it cannot find the `quarto` command which is installed in the `cm-job` job. My expectation was that that would be available in `test reuse` or is it just data that can be passed around like this? I can't quite see why this isn't working across the workflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs are executed on fresh agent. So if you installed something before you need to install it again on your new job.

An overcome for this you can use composite action to keep your code DRY and then share this composite action whenever you need install additional software on runner.

Another option is to use self-hosted runner where you pre-install needed packages. For this you can use for instance [container jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/customizing-the-containers-used-by-jobs).

Comment: ugh. so there is no way to consolidate steps like that? like if i have 10 workflows that all need this installation, i have to maintain separate steps for each one?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.  You can use composite action for this and reuse it to keep your code DRY.

Comment: The composite answer is the real one I think. Happy for you to put that as an answer or I can reproduce myself.

Comment: @boshek could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?